# Rank-ordering output from proc logistic

Tags: sas

In the SAS proc logistic output, is there a way to rank-order by decreasing value of Wald's Chi square statistic?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_ods_examples04.htm) to an example of using ODS to write procedure output to a SAS dataset. The example uses proc genmod, but the concept applies to proc logistic as well. The documentation for proc logistic contains all of the ODS table names produced by the proc. Find the one you are interested in, write it out to a data set, and sort it however you desire.

Comment: Exactly; the workflow in SAS is 1) run the procedure you wish -> 2) examine the Output, find the section of interest and determine the name of a corresponding ODS table -> 3) using the ODS name, save that output to a table -> 4) work with this table, re-ordering it as you wish.